# Regarding sharepoint and SQL data store

Tags: sql, sharepoint, datasource

I have to create a web form and store all kinds of data from the page, the data will be text, num, email and checkboxes.

I have to store them in a database SQL. I have to deploy the same page in the sharepoint server and users will be able to use that page to fillin the details once the details are filled in it should be loaded in to the SQL seperate databse.

could anybody tell me what would be the best approach.

Please give me rough idea so that I will take the steps to get it complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use a SQL database?  You could simply use SharePoint lists for this type of functionality.

If you HAVE to use SQL then look at Business Connectivity Services through SharePoint Designer 2010, or if you are using WSS 3.0 or MOSS 2007 then look at creating custom web parts.